# Double or triple 45 degree hatch in GeoServer - possible?

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

My end goal is to have a style like this in GeoServer:

[image: Triple hatch]
[image: Double hatch]

I have tried using ExternalGraphic in SLD but that only seems to work with vertical/horizontal hatch.

Edit: 
By using ExternalGraphic with 45 degree hatch i get a offset like: 
[image: offset]

sld:

```
<sld:ExternalGraphic>
  <sld:OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="file:/C:/Users/asawea/Desktop/1012.png"/>
  <sld:Format>image/png</sld:Format>
</sld:ExternalGraphic>
```

Tips?

Comment: What does not work with external graphics?

Comment: Updated question. @IanTurton

Comment: is this a tiled wms request?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Hatching fill</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>SLD Cook Book: Hatching fill</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#cccccc</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#232323</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <GraphicFill>
                <Graphic>
                  <Mark>
                    <WellKnownName>shape://slash</WellKnownName>
                    <Stroke>
                      <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffff00</CssParameter>
                      <CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                  </Mark>
                  <Size>20</Size>
                  <Rotation>
                    <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
                  </Rotation>
                </Graphic>
              </GraphicFill>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: You have two polygonsymbolizer

Comment: On can have as many polygon symbolizers as needed, it's valid SLD.

Comment: This works for double hatching, but how can i add one more GraphicFill that has an offset equal to the stroke-width?